# C++ debug: two-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, debugging, vector

I want to populate a vector of vectors of strings, so that it's multidimensional. I have the following vectors:

```
[<start>, The <object> <verb> tonight.]
[<object>, waves, big yellow flowers, slugs]
[<verb>, sigh <adverb>, portend like <object>, die <adverb>]
[<adverb>, warily, grumpily]
```

And I want to add them to a vector in this way:

```
vector<vector<string>> vector2;
```

So that it would look like this:

```
vector2[0]: [<start>, The <object> <verb> tonight.]
vector2[1]: [<object>, waves, big yellow flowers, slugs]
vector2[2]: [<verb>, sigh <adverb>, portend like <object>, die <adverb>]
vector2[3]: [<adverb>, warily, grumpily]
```

This is the code I have:

```
    vector<vector<string>> vector2;

    //the populated vector 1 is not shown here
    for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
    {
        vector<string> vs = split_def(vector1[i]);
        //calls a function that splits a string at index i of vector1
       //by a certain character and stores the fragments in vector vs

        cout << vs << endl;
       //Note: I have an overloaded output operator function for vectors

        /*for(int j = 0; j < vs.size(); j++)
        {
            vector2[i].push_back(vs[j]);
            cout << vector2[i][j] << endl;
        }*/

    }
```

The part that's making my program crash is the part that I have commented out between /* */. Everything before that works. I'm assuming that my logic is correct, it's just the syntax that's wrong. Populating that vector is what's giving me the issue. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `vector2[i]` is uninitialized when you're accessing it.

Comment: I tried doing `vector2[i][j] = vs[j];` and it still crashed

Comment: I noticed that the vector I originally had was splitDefs but in my code it's vector2. I changed it for consistency (and also to simplify) but they're the same vector. I edited it.

Comment: You need `vector2.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());` inside the loop.

Comment: You're trying to fix a bug without understanding it. *You may not do things to `vector2[0]` when `vector2` is still uninitialized.*

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Inside the outside loop or the inner loop?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you need to add the vector you're creating to vector2:

```
vector<vector<string>> vector2;

//the populated vector 1 is not shown here
for(int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
{
    vector<string> vs = split_def(vector1[i]);
    //calls a function that splits a string at index i of vector1
   //by a certain character and stores the fragments in vector vs

    cout << vs << endl;
   //Note: I have an overloaded output operator function for vectors

   vector2.emplace_back(vs);

}
```